# War playing cards based game

Tags: python, game, playing-cards

How can I make this "War" card game code more visibly pleasing?

```
import random
import sys

class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit, value):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
        self.name = str(self.rank) + " of " + self.suit

class War:
    def wincards(self, winner, deck):
        i = 0
        n = len(deck)
        while i < n:
            winner.append(deck[0])
            deck.remove(deck[0])
            i = i + 1

    def playcards(self, player1, player2, deck):
        if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
            deck.append(player2[0])
            deck.append(player1[0])
        else:
            deck.append(player1[0])
            deck.append(player2[0])

    def comparecards(self, deck):
        if deck[0] > deck[1]:
            return 0
        if deck[0] < deck[1]:
            return 2
        if deck[0] == deck[1]:
            return 1

    def create_deck(self):
        suit = ['Spades', 'Hearts', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds']
        rank = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']
        deck = []
        num = 2
        for i in suit:
            for x in rank:
                deck.append(Card(x, i, num))
                num = num + 1
            num = 2  
        return sorted(deck, key=lambda k: random.random())

    def deal_cards(self, deck):  
        x = 0
        i = 0
        player1 = []
        player2 = []
        while i < len(deck):
            if x == 0:
                player1.append(deck[i])
                x = 1
            else:
                player2.append(deck[i])
                x = 0
            i += 1
        return player1, player2

    def game(self):
        pl1wins = 0
        pl2wins = 0
        turnspl1 = []
        turnspl2 = []
        while (pl1wins + pl2wins) < 100: 
            deck = self.create_deck()
            players = self.deal_cards(deck)
            player1 = players[0]
            player2 = players[1]

            player1 = sorted(player1, key=lambda card: card.value, reverse = True)
            war = []

            turns = 0
            while len(player1) > 0 and len(player2) > 0:
                turns = turns + 1
                if (len(player1) + len(player2)) > 52:
                    print "Oh NO!"
                    sys.exit()

                war = []
                self.playcards(player1, player2, war) 

                player1.remove(player1[0])
                player2.remove(player2[0])
                result = self.comparecards(war)
                if result == 0:
                    warGame.wincards(player1, war)
                elif result == 2:
                    warGame.wincards(player2, war)

                elif result == 1:
                    if len(player1) == 0:
                        player1.append(war[0])
                        war.remove(war[0])
                        if player1[0].value == player2[0].value:
                            player1[0].value = 0
                    if len(player2) == 0:
                        player2.append(war[1])
                        war.remove(war[1])
                        if player1[0].value == player2[0].value:
                            player2[0].value = 0
                    while len(war) > 0:
                        i = 0
                        for i in range(3):
                            if len(player1) > 1:
                                war.append(player1[0])
                                player1.remove(player1[0])

                            if len(player2) > 1:   
                                war.append(player2[0])
                                player2.remove(player2[0])

                        if player1[0].value > player2[0].value:
                            self.playcards(player1, player2, war)
                            self.wincards(player1, war)

                        elif player1[0].value < player2[0].value:
                            self.playcards(player1, player2, war)
                            self.wincards(player2, war)

            if len(player1) != 0:
                pl1wins = pl1wins + 1
                turnspl1.append(turns)
            elif len(player2) != 0:
                pl2wins = pl2wins + 1
                turnspl2.append(turns)
        print str(pl1wins) + " versus " + str(pl2wins)
        print str(average(turnspl1)) + " versus " + str(average(turnspl2))
        print str(average(turnspl1 + turnspl2))

def average(array):
    a = 0
    for i in array:
        a = a + i

    average = a/len(array)
    return average

warGame = War()    
warGame.game()
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Looping over lists

When looping over elements of a collection,
if you don't really need the loop index,
then use an iterating `for` loop instead of a `while` loop:

> ```
>     i = 0
>     while i < len(deck):
>         if x == 0:
>             player1.append(deck[i])
>             x = 1
>         else:
>             player2.append(deck[i])
>             x = 0
>         i += 1
> ```

This accomplishes the same, but cleaner and more natural:

```
    for card in deck:
        if x == 0:
            player1.append(card)
            x = 1
        else:
            player2.append(card)
            x = 0
```

#### More simplifications

On top of @Ethan's review, some further simplifications are possible.

---

This method appends the content of `deck` at the end of `winner`,
and empties the `deck`:

> ```
> def wincards(self, winner, deck):
>     i = 0
>     n = len(deck)
>     while i < n:
>         winner.append(deck[0])
>         deck.remove(deck[0])
>         i = i + 1
> ```

A simpler way to accomplish the same thing:

```
def wincards(winner, deck):
    winner.extend(deck)
    deck[:] = []
```

---

In your implementation of `average`, you reinvented the wheel by implementing `sum`, which exists as a built-in function in Python.
You could reduce your implementation to one line:

```
def average(array):
    return sum(array) / len(array)
```

---

In this sequence of conditions,
if the first two conditions are both `False`,
then inevitably `deck[0] == deck[1]`,
so you don't need the last `if` statement and can `return 1` directly:

> ```
>     if deck[0] > deck[1]:
>         return 0
>     if deck[0] < deck[1]:
>         return 2
>     if deck[0] == deck[1]:
>         return 1
> ```

#### Naming

Many of the variable names are not great.
For example in this bit:

> ```
>     suit = ['Spades', 'Hearts', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds']
>     rank = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']
>     deck = []
>     num = 2
>     for i in suit:
>         for x in rank:
>             # ...
> ```

It's often natural to give lists plural names,
such as "suits" and "ranks".
(On the other hand, "deck" is fine as it is, because it already implies a collection of cards.)

Then, these better names will also enable you to use better names than "i" and "x" when you loop:

```
    for suit in suits:
        for rank in ranks:
            # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

## Proper class inheritance

In any version of Python 2.x, all classes need to explicitly inherit from `object`, like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...
```

If you do use Python 3.x, you don't need to explicitly inherit from `object`. For more info on this, see [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374857/should-all-python-classes-extend-object).

---

## `str.format` rather than concatenation

Consider the following line:

```
print str(pl1wins) + " versus " + str(pl2wins)
```

We can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) rather than concatenation to get rid of the calls to `str`, and make this clearer and easier to read.

```
print "{0} versus {1}".format(pl1wins, pl2wins)
```

---

## Simplification

The following statement:

```
turns = turns + 1
```

Can be simplified using the addition assignment operator, `+=`, like this:

```
turns += 1
```

This also applies to other operators, like mathematical, and binary.

There are a few places where you're chaining `if`/`elif`/`else` statements. You can use a dictionary instead, like this:

```
options = {
    1: some_function
    ...
}

if some_input in options:
    options[some_input]()
else:
    ...
```

---

## Miscellaneous nitpicks

I only have on nitpick, and that's the addition of `if __name__ == "__main__":` to the end, like this.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    war_game = War()
    war_game.game()
```

See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for more details.